# C++で外部ライブラリをソースコードごと利用する方法を教えてください。

Tags: c++, cmake

## 環境

C++20
Cmake 3.16
Clion

## 質問

最近やっとcmakeを使った共有ライブラリの使い方を知ったばかりなのですが、今度はgithub上にあるライブラリをソースコードごとプロジェクトに含めたいです。
[MSDetour](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/releases)というライブラリなのですが、そもそもこういうのはソースコードを自分でビルドして何らかのファイル形式にしてから使うものなのか、そのまま使えるのかすら知りません。ソースフォルダの中にMakefileというファイルがあるので、やはり何らかにビルドするというのが基本なんでしょうか？

とりあえずダウンロードしたフォルダのsrcを`MSDetour`に改名したうえでプロジェクトに含んで、cmake内に

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MSDetour)
```

などとしたんですが、メインファイルで#include "detours.h"としても使えません。

どうしたらいいでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この手のプロジェクトはたいてい `README` とか `FAQ` とか、読めばそれなりに理解できるドキュメントがくっついてきます（ドキュメントライター募集中、なんてプロジェクトもよく見かけます）
`Detours` にも https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/FAQ ページがあったりして、これによると（オレオレ翻訳）

Q. `detour.lib` と `detour.h` はどこにありますか？
A. あなたの C/C++ コンパイラで `detours/src` ディレクトリ中のソースコードをビルドしてください。そのためには `detour` ディレクトリまたは `detour/src` ディレクトリで `nmake` と入力します。

ということで、自分でビルドしないと `detour.h` は存在しないようです。他にもいくつか注意事項があるようなので、まずは FAQ ページの内容に従ってみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、READMEに詳しい情報がなかったため悩んでいましたが、そういう場合はwikiに書かれていることがあるんですね！
windowsでコマンドを使うのってunixと比べて色々めんどくさそうだったのであまり外部コマンドを使ったことはなかったんですが、この場合どうしてもnmakeを入れないといけなそうですね～。。
了解です、ありがとうございました！

Comment: 調べたところ、nmakeはVisual Studioと一緒に入ってるみたいですね！開発者コマンドプロンプトからnmakeを実行できました！